# Explicitly implemented interface and generic constraint

Tags: c#, generics, explicit-interface

```
interface IBar { void Hidden(); }

class Foo : IBar { public void Visible() { /*...*/ } void IBar.Hidden() { /*...*/ } }

class Program
{
    static T CallHidden1<T>(T foo) where T : Foo
    {
        foo.Visible();
        ((IBar)foo).Hidden();   //Cast required

        return foo;
    }

    static T CallHidden2<T>(T foo) where T : Foo, IBar
    {
        foo.Visible();
        foo.Hidden();   //OK

        return foo;
    }
}
```

Is there any difference (CallHidden1 vs. CallHidden2) is actual compiled code?
Is there other differences between where T : Foo and where T : Foo, IBar (if Foo implements IBar) that in accessing explicitly implemented interface members ?

Answer (score 6):

The IL generated is slightly different:

```
    L_000d: ldarg.0 
    L_000e: box !!T
    L_0013: callvirt instance void WindowsFormsApplication1.IBar::Hidden()
```

vs.

```
    L_000d: ldarga.s foo
    L_000f: constrained !!T
    L_0015: callvirt instance void WindowsFormsApplication1.IBar::Hidden()
```

If `T` were a value type, this would result in `foo` being boxed in `CallHidden1` but not in `CallHidden2`.  However, since `Foo` is a class, any type `T` derived from `Foo` will not be a value type, and thus the behavior will be identical.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a tiny bit, since the second specifies that the interface must be implemented, which may become important if `Foo` is later changed so that it does not implement `IBar`.

That would make it unsuitable for being used in `CallHidden2<>` while remaining valid at compile time for `CallHidden1<>` (which would then fail at runtime if `IBar` is no longer being implemented by `Foo`).

So if they are in separate assemblies, the different metadata would make a difference. The executed IL will, however, be pretty similar if not the same.