# C#: Shared struct fields and inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, struct

Now I know that C# doesn't support inheritance of structs for a number of reasons.
I was wondering however, if it is still possible to implement some form of hierarchy for data types such that a function can rely on a variable of type B or type C having field x because they both inherit from type A.

More specific:
I have two structs that have a value field and coordinates (2D and 3D)

```
public struct BarDataPoint
{
    public TwoTuple<float> coords { get; }
    public float value { get; }
    public BarDataPoint(TwoTuple<float> coords, float value)
    {
        this.coords = coords;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public struct ScatterDataPoint
{
    public ThreeTuple<float> coords { get; }
    public float value { get; }
    public ScatterDataPoint(ThreeTuple<float> coords, float value)
    {
        this.coords = coords;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I also have this function that is supposed to find the maximum value of an array of data points

```
    {
        // Finds the maximum value of an BarData array
        float maxValue = data[0].value;
        foreach (BarDataPoint dataPoint in data)
        {
            maxValue = (maxValue < dataPoint.value) ? dataPoint.value : maxValue;
        }
        return maxValue;
    }
```

I would like to generalize this function, so that it can take both types (or any other type with a "value" field) and return its maximum value.

Is this possible? If yes, how? Or would you recommend a completely different design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no problems having a struct implement an interface:

```
public interface IDataPoint
{
    float Value { get; }
}

public struct BarDataPoint : IDataPoint
public struct ScatterDataPoint : IDataPoint
```

Then you could do this:

```
{
    float maxValue = data[0].Value;
    foreach (IDataPoint dataPoint in data)
    {
        maxValue = (maxValue < dataPoint.Value) ? dataPoint.Value : maxValue;
    }
    return maxValue;
}
```

---

To avoid the performance hit caused by boxing in the above example, you could make the implementing method generic:

```
float GetMaxValue<TDataPoint>(TDataPoint[] data) where TDataPoint : IDataPoint
{
    float maxValue = data[0].Value;
    foreach (TDataPoint dataPoint in data)
    {
        maxValue = (maxValue < dataPoint.Value) ? dataPoint.Value : maxValue;
    }
    return maxValue;
}
```

Just be sure to always refer to data as `TDataPoint` within the generic method, as using `IDataPoint` will cause boxing (because interfaces are reference types).

The reason this works is because the generic method will be resolved to either `float GetMaxValue(BarDataPoint[] data)` or `float GetMaxValue(ScatterDataPoint[] data)` and not `float GetMaxValue(IDataPoint[] data)`.

---

As an aside, if you simply need to know the maximum value, [`Enumerable.Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Max__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) should do exactly what you're after, without the need for the above approach:

```
BarDataPoint[] data = //...
float max = data.Max(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: This might cause a performance problem due to boxing.

Comment: And [here's an SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5531948/3094533) that explains how the usage of generics avoid the need of boxing. +1.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for!